# 11 ways to get past the Wall

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I came upon a wall across a path that I traversed
Without a route around it I cried foul with mighty curse!
I soon however noticed a door fixed on this divide
It wouldn't budge even when shoved no matter what I tried

To reach my destination I must find a thoroughfare
Or open this partition using anything I dare
I searched my person, hereabouts or down on nearby ground
A length of rope should give me hope, alas none could be found

A dram might help assuage my fears, or if I sprouted wings
Some compound or a bunch of tools, if I could source such things
In total half a dozen ways to pass sprang to my mind
Though this moment (I could lament) Fate hasn't been so kind

With doorway stuck by such warped wood; alone, I'm at a loss
A shout to find assistance could give me a chance to cross
I heard a disembodied voice; gatekeeper could this be?
Another soul could help this hole permit entry to me

Their support would be welcomed if my plight I could evince
A single of five schemes could have this stranger soon convinced
Outright I calculated eleven ways to advance
To make my choice will cause rejoice! This wall shall watch me dance

These answers have in common what will seem so obvious
To anyone that detects what is missing from this verse
My question then becomes: what options have I thought to try?

Answer (score 5):

More than 11, but I was uncertain about a few of them ...

(if someone can edit this so that each number is on a separate line, I would be thankful and learn something)

> 1) try  (simply try to open the door)
>  2) pry  (open the partition using something)
>  3) tie  (rope)
>  4a) * rye  (whiskey/dram/fears -- stretch)
>  5) fly  (over)
>  6) lye  (soap compound)
>  7) ply  (tools)
>  8) dry  (the warped wood -- a stretch)
>  9) pry  (need help prying [alone at a loss])
>  10) hi   (shout hello)
>  11) cry  (convince)
>  5 schemes with gatekeeper
>  12) buy  (pay your way through)
>  13) vie  (gamble your way through)
>  14) lie  (tell her she's skinny)
>  15) pie  (bake him some goodies)
>  4b) rye  (get the gatekeeper drunk and take her keys)

Ok I will reduce based on feedback ...

Edit 1

> 2) pry  (open the partition using something)
>  5) fly  (over)
>  6) lye  (soap compound)
>  7) ply  (tools)
>  8) dry  (the warped wood -- a stretch)
>
>  5 schemes with gatekeeper
>
>  11) cry  (convince)
>  12) buy  (pay your way through)
>  14) lie  (tell her she's skinny)
>  4b) rye  (get the gatekeeper drunk and take her keys)
>
>  Still seems like "tie/rope" should be one the first 6, especially with this line "A length of rope should give me hope, alas none could be found"

Comment: You have a lot of them, but there were only 6 that do not involve the gatekeeper. 2/9, 5, 6, 7 & 8 are correct, 11 should be one of the schemes, along with 12, 14 and 4b. 9 out of 11 so far!

Comment: Tempt with pie or rye (alcohol).